# Проблема с туториалом Django Girls

Tags: python, django

Cтолкнулся с проблемой в туториале **Django Girls** , а именно:
нужно включить эту строку кода в файл `blog/views.py`, добавив её в функцию `def post_list(request)`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts=Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())\
    .order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})
```

После чего мне нужно отразить шаблон списка записей в **html** файле для моего сайта

```
 <div>
   <h1><a href=''>Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
 </div>

 {{ posts }}
```

Но этот код не работает, отображается только первый `div`. Остальные посты не работают, и ошибки никакой не появляется, поэтому не знаю, как пофиксить.

Конечно тут виной всему мои корявые руки, буду благодарен если откроете глаза, в чем подвох

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в шаблон передаёте пустой контекст. Надо так:

```
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Да и в самом шаблоне выведется только строковое представление QuerySet'а вместо `{{ posts }}`, а это явно не то, что вы ожидаете. Наверняка там должен быть цикл:

```
<div>
   <h1><a href=''>Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
</div>

{% for post in posts %}    
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)